# Google Maps Static Postcode Area

Tags: google-maps

When you type an outcode (first part of a postcode) into google maps it outlines that area for you (e.g. [Outline of B7](https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?q=B7&hl=en&sll=52.505221,-1.81541&sspn=0.436343,1.352692&hnear=Birmingham%20B7,%20United%20Kingdom&t=m&z=13))

How can this be achieved with the Google Static Maps, any ideas?  If you search for just postcode it centres but doesn't draw the outline of the outcode which is specifically what I need.